# ammo.js after calling applyTorque how to update the force direction?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, physics, ammo.js

I am using ammo.js to create a simple demo.

I have a 3d object in the world and I can make it move with the following code:

```
cubeObject.applyForce(new Vec3(10, 0, 0));
```

It will move along the x-axis and then stop gradually.

Now I want to make it to turn a little bit (imagine a car turning):

```
cubeObject.applyTorque(new Vec3(0, 1000, 0));
```

After calling this code, the cube (car) dose turn a certain degree (this is good as expected).

But the problem is, the car is still moving along the x-axis instead of moving towards the direction it is facing (after turning).

I do not know what I am missing here.

Any advice will be appreciated, thank :)

Comment: You're missing wheels basically. Applying torque to a moving object doesn't change its direction. The object stopping gradually implies friction, which is exactly what makes the angled wheels of a car turn the car.

Comment: I am trying to make the demo as simple as it can be so I tried to just use a cube to simulate a car. After applying the torque the cube dose look turned (it changed its direction). So, is it possible to achieve what I need ( the cube move towards its facing direction) with just a single cube object ?

Comment: Well, you can keep applying force to the car based on their current direction. Instead of `new Vec3(10, 0, 0)` you use `new Vec3(speed * Math.cos(a), 0, speed * Math.sin(a))` where `a` is the current angle of the car.

Comment: I did tried this. And the car did turned and move towards its direction. But the problem is the force of the car is changing to slow using v * Math.cos(a), v * Math.sin(a). For example: the car is moving with speed :(x:100, y:0). Then I turn the car 90 degree, but the car will keep moving along x-axis for quite a long distance then turn a 90 degree which looks very unnatural ...

Comment: Well, ammojs is a physics engine. You can either do [this](http://kripken.github.io/ammo.js/examples/webgl_demo_vehicle/index.html) using ammo/physics or implement your own driving by simply changing the cube's position and rotation.